# How to test Django Form ImageField

Tags: python, django

I want to test my imageform, I provide all required data, still it giving me an error. Does anyone know, how to test form's ImageField?

my model is

```
class Image(CustomModel):

    path = models.ImageField(_('Path'), upload_to=get_file_path,
                             help_text=_('Represents a path of an image.'))

    caption = models.CharField(_('Caption'), max_length=128,
                               null=False, blank=False,
                               db_column='caption',
                               help_text=_('128 characters max.')

    meta_info = models.TextField(_("Image MetaInfo"), null=False, blank=False,
                                help_text=_('Image meta info'),
                                default='{}', db_column='meta_info')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Created At'), null=False,
                                      db_column='created_at', blank=False,
                                      help_text=_('Date time at which image was created.'),
                                      default=datetime.now())
```

My form:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            """
            Meta class for Image form
            """
            model = Image
            fields = ('caption', 'path', 'status','meta_info')
            widgets = {
                'meta_info': forms.HiddenInput(),
            }
```

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

My test method:

```
def test_form_valid(self):
            """
            """
            self.tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
            path = os.path.join(self.tmp_dir,"a376140b-054f-4329-82e1-f271af5cfcaf.png")
            form = ImageForm({'caption':'image', 'path':path, 'status':'A', "created_at":timezone.now(),
                             'meta_info':"{\"id\":2,\"type\":\"Q\",\"lang_id\":1}"})
            print(form.is_valid())
            print(form.errors)
            assert form.is_valid(), 'should be valid'
```

Traceback:

```
   def test_form_valid(self):
        """
            """
        self.tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        path = os.path.join(self.tmp_dir,"a376140b-054f-4329-82e1-f271af5cfcaf.png")
        form = ImageForm({'caption':'image', 'path':path, 'status':'A', "created_at":timezone.now(),
                         'meta_info':"{\"id\":2,\"type\":\"Q\",\"lang_id\":1}"})
        print(form.is_valid())
        print(form.errors)
>       assert form.is_valid(), 'should be valid'
E       AssertionError: should be valid
E       assert False
E        +  where False = <bound method BaseForm.is_valid of <ImageForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(caption;path;status;meta_info)>>()
E        +    where <bound method BaseForm.is_valid of <ImageForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(caption;path;status;meta_info)>> = <ImageForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(caption;path;status;meta_info)>.is_valid

droana/apps/test_manager/test/test_views.py:269: AssertionError
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------
Installed 1320 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
False
<ul class="errorlist"><li>path<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
__
```

I tried solution for testing imagefield but that doesn't work for me.
Does anyone know how to test imagefield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be：

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
....
data = {'caption':'image', 'status':'A', "created_at":timezone.now(), 'meta_info':"{\"id\":2,\"type\":\"Q\",\"lang_id\":1}"}
form = ImageForm(data, {'path':SimpleUploadedFile('filename.png', 'data')})
```

So when you're trying to bind file data with the form, you should always put the file info into a `UploadedFile` object and construct the form with two parameters.

And [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files) is the example from Django Doc